# How to remove kubernetes completely from Ubuntu node

Tags: ubuntu, kubernetes, kubeadm

We need to completely remove Kubernetes from Ubuntu 18.04 server.

For that we [tried](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59534821/completely-remove-kubernetes)

```
kubeadm reset

sudo apt-get purge kubeadm kubectl kubelet kubernetes-cni kube*
```

It gives

> Package 'kubeadm' is not installed, so not removed
> Package 'kubectl' is not installed, so not removed
> Package 'kubelet' is not installed, so not removed
> Package 'kubernetes-cni' is not installed, so not removed

If we run `kubeadm version`

> kubeadm version: &version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"21", GitVersion:"v1.21.3", GitCommit:"ca643a4d1f7bfe34773c74f79527be4afd95bf39", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2021-07-15T21:03:28Z", GoVersion:"go1.16.6", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}

`which kubeadm`

```
/usr/local/bin/kubeadm
```

`dpkg -S /usr/local/bin/kubeadm`

```
dpkg-query: no path found matching pattern /usr/local/bin/kubeadm
```

`snap list --all`

> No snaps are installed yet. Try 'snap install hello-world'

We had installed Kubernetes using no source compiling locally.

```
curl -s https://packages.cloud.google.com/apt/doc/apt-key.gpg | sudo apt-key
add
sudo apt-add-repository "deb http://apt.kubernetes.io/ kubernetes-xenial main"
sudo apt update
sudo apt install kubeadm kubelet kubectl
sudo apt-mark hold kubeadm kubelet kubectl
```

What is the issue here? How can I properly remove Kubernetes from this node?

Comment: The question is not really about kubernetes because after `kubeadm reset` settings are removed (however some traces can be left). There are different options what can be done with `broken` packages, e.g. [try with dpkg or other options from this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/438365) or [I've seen it's possible to install them and then remove properly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42809946/not-able-to-remove-a-package-completely-in-ubuntu#comment72732818_42809946). Also! Sounds obvious, but nowadays it's much faster to recreate a VM.

Comment: Hello @SachithMuhandiram. Any updates?

Answer (score 1):

Both the [Kubernetes documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/production-environment/tools/kubeadm/create-cluster-kubeadm/#tear-down) and [this page on webhostinggeeks.com](https://webhostinggeeks.com/howto/how-to-uninstall-kubernetes-on-ubuntu/) describe how to tear down a kubernetes installation.

Per the K8S doc:

1. Use `kubectl config delete-cluster` to delete your local references. If you want to deprovision your cluster more cleanly, then
2. `kubectl drain <node name> --delete-emptydir-data --force --ignore-daemonsets` drain the node
3. `kubeadm reset` Reset the state
4. `iptables -F && iptables -t nat -F && iptables -t mangle -F && iptables -X` manually reset iptables
5. `kubectl delete node <node name>` remove the node
6. `kubeadm reset` on the control plane to trigger a best effort clean up.

From webhostinggeeks.com:

1. `kubectl delete all --all-namespaces --all` delete all k8s resources
2. `sudo apt-get purge kubeadm kubectl kubelet kubernetes-cni kube*`
   `sudo apt-get autoremove` Uninstall kubeadm, kubectl, and kubelet
3. `sudo rm -rf ~/.kube /etc/cni /etc/kubernetes /var/lib/etcd /var/lib/kubelet` remove artifacts
4. `sudo iptables -F && sudo iptables -t nat -F && sudo iptables -t mangle -F && sudo iptables -X` reset iptables
5. Manually revert any changes to `/etc/hosts` file

Comment: Can you please add the information from the links to this post to make it a complete answer? Leave the links for attribution and further research, but the main points of the solution should be here in this post.